Copying from S3 to Windows Network drive
I have a very small hard drive and an expansive Windows network drive. I would like to copy the bucket "myBucket" to my Microsoft local area network shared drive.
Something like this, but not this because it doesn't work.
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/ \\network\drive\path\ --profile my-profile

The above command thinks about it for a while,and returns a new line with no changes.
I have also tried
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/ . --profile my-profile

I am surprised there are no error messages.
Chat GPT says I need to download this to a local drive first and then copy to the network drive, but my hard drive is too small (the data set 1.1 TB). Any advice?
Edit: Interesting, cp did not work but sync did. Why is that?

Interesting, 'cp' did not work but 'sync' did. Why is that?
The command was
aws s3 sync s3://myBucket/ . --profile my-profile


probably because "s3 cp" requires either an object name, or "--recursive", to copy multiple items from a source, but "s3 sync" does not, it is recursive automatically.

Hi and welcome! Unfortunately, you aren't providing an answer to the question :-( Once you've got enough reputation you will be able to comment on posts but until then please provide answers only (and ones that don't require clarification from the asker).  https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation
